# Calling plain JavaScript code from Angular changes the "this" reference

Tags: javascript, angular, callback

I am developing a web application that has both Angular components and plain JavaScript code. Angular can call plain JavaScript code all OK, but there is something strange going on when using callbacks.

Suppose I have this kind of plain JavaScript code:

```
var MyLibrary = {};
MyLibrary.doStuff = function (callback) {
  console.log("I am doing stuff here!");
  callback();
}
```

I am calling this from an Angular component like this:

```
callDoStuff() {
  MyLibrary.doStuff(this.proceed);
}

proceed() {
  console.log("Here we are back in Angular");
}
```

But this doesn't work. The call to MyLibrary.doStuff() works but it is unable to call Angular back.

I have developed a workaround where I have a JavaScript variable on the page that loads the Angular component (not in the template of the component itself), let's call it "angular" and then I do this in Angular:

```
ngOnInit() {
  angular = this;
}

callDoStuff() {
  MyLibrary.doStuff(angular.proceed);
}

proceed() {
  console.log("Here we are back in Angular");
}
```

This works, but now I have to use "angular" instead of "this" in every function that is called in the same function chain. Why is this happening, and is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Please show us a more complete example of your component so we can have a better idea contextually what you are working with

Comment: One way to get it to work is to replace `MyLibrary.doStuff(this.proceed);` with `MyLibrary.doStuff(this.proceed.bind(this));`

Comment: (To clarify, that would be needed if the `proceed` method had `this` references inside it - which I assume in your real use case it does. But when it doesn't, as in the code you've provided here, you don't need to do anything.)

Comment: You can also do `MyLibrary.doStuff(() => this.proceed())` to keep the `this` set as expected

Comment: You are right, the proceed method, and the methods it calls, have this references inside them in my real use case.